# Corona Database Working on simulator but not on android device, stops on previous scene, using storyboard

Tags: database, sqlite, storyboard, coronasdk

I am using database to keep the highscore record. On storyboard scene change i make file to display highscore. I make database first, then table, then retrieve the record. Check if now made score is more than the existing in database. Update the first existing record.

Its working perfectly fine on the simulator, but on device it stucks on the previous scene and never changes the scene to the highscore file.

It was changing scene before database was implemented.

```
local myData = require("myData")

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --         DATABASE
    --         SQLite

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

            --Include sqlite
    require "sqlite3"

    local path = system.pathForFile("myDataBaseASDF.db", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    db = sqlite3.open( path )   

    --Handle the applicationExit event to close the db
    local function onSystemEvent( event )
        if( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then              
            db:close()
        end
    end


    local tablesetup = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highScoreClassic (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Time, Taps);]]
    print("DB Created")
    db:exec( tablesetup )


    local dbRows = 0
    local dbTaps = 0
    local dbTime = "00:00:00"

    --print all the table contents
    for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM highScoreClassic WHERE id=1;") do
        dbRows = dbRows + 1
        dbTaps = row.Taps
        dbTime = row.Time
        print("Row Taken")
    end

    function isHighscore()
        if myData.currentScore > dbTime then
            return true
        elseif myData.currentScore == dbTime and myData.taps > dbTaps then
            return true
        elseif myData.currentScore == dbTime and myData.taps < dbTaps then
            return false
        else return false end
    end

    function saveToDataBase() 
        print("updating")
        local q = [[UPDATE highScoreClassic SET Time=']]..myData.currentScore..[[', Taps=]]..myData.taps..[[ WHERE id=1;]]
        db:exec( q )
    end

    function saveToDataBaseFirstTime()
        print("inserting")
        local tablefill =[[INSERT INTO highScoreClassic VALUES (NULL, ']]..myData.currentScore..[[',']]..myData.taps..[['); ]]
        db:exec( tablefill )
    end

    if ( dbRows > 0 ) then
        if ( isHighscore() ) then
            print(dbTime, dbTaps)
            myData.highScore = true
            saveToDataBase()
        else
            myData.highScore = false
            print("No HighScore")
        end

    else
        saveToDataBaseFirstTime()
    end



    --setup the system listener to catch applicationExit
    Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be careful with case sensitive stuff on your device. It's not case sensitive in simulator, but it is on your device.

also make sure the path is correct for your device.

Answer (score 0):

file in simulator DocumentsDirectory wont be included in your device. you have to create the file again.